# Product Cart - > Moneris: two currency

Tags: asp-classic

We are attemption to customize the script to allow Canadian clients to process orders in CND dollars and all other clients to process orders in USD; however, we cannot authenticate with Moneris. Why is this script not authenticating?

we have modified 1 file.

gwMoneris2.asp - there we do the switch between gateway accounts depending of shipping country and display USD or CAD. The account info is hardcoded in that file as it was before update. Also we added there separate storeid/key for testing mode.

*added code*

gwMoneris2.asp

```
'// Set gateway specific variables - modified by egr-se
' Select account depending on Shipping country
if pcShippingCountryCode <> "CA" then
    pcPay_Moneris_StoreId="245ZGD2111"
    pcPay_Moneris_Key="dpQ87CRAVGP5"
else
    pcPay_Moneris_StoreId="AXVRQ47259"
    pcPay_Moneris_Key="dpNLNKHNYK6N"
end if
pcPay_Moneris_TransType=1
pcPay_Moneris_Lang="en-ca"
pcPay_Moneris_Testmode=0
pcv_CVV=0
pcPay_Moneris_Meth = 1
pcPay_Moneris_Interac =0

' Test mode id and key
if pcPay_Moneris_Testmode = 1 then
    pcPay_Moneris_StoreId="HBHTA8ore1"
    pcPay_Moneris_Key="dp1YDH2GJQR2"
end if
```

and line

```
 <td><p><%=money(pcBillingTotal)%> <%if pcShippingCountryCode = "CA" 
      then%>CAD<%else%>USD<%end if%>$</p></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on this part of your code (the key starts with dp), it looks like your trying to setup a DirectPost integration:

```
pcPay_Moneris_StoreId="AXVRQ47259"

pcPay_Moneris_Key="dpNLNKHNYK6N"
```

In order to add support for USD currency the actual steps will vary based on the merchant account type (Canada merchant account vs. USA merchant account). The type of merchant account you have depends on where your bank account is located: bank accounts based in Canada will use the Canadian payment gateway (it supports both CDN and USD currencies) and bank accounts located in the US will use the USA payment gateway (it supports USD currency).

To recap here, are the possibilities:

Canadian bank account- CDN currency account (merchant account number will start with 003)

Canadian bank account- USD currency account (merchant account number will start with 003)

USA bank account- USD currency account (merchant account number will start with 295)

If you have a working integration with a Canada CDN account then setting up a Canada USD account is a piece of cake, you just login to your Canada USD merchant account, create your DirectPost config and copy and paste the credentials into your program (like in your example above).

However:

If you have a USA USD merchant account then the above steps won't work since the USA gateway has slightly different integration than the Canada gateway. You'll need to download the USA DirectPost Integration Guide from developer.moneris.com and use that to create another integration for the USA gateway.

For example:

Here's how you send a DirectPost purchase to the Canada Gateway (CDN and USD):

```
<FORM METHOD=”POST” ACTION=https://esqa.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php> 
<INPUT TYPE=”HIDDEN” NAME=”ps_store_id” VALUE=”AF4Fs1024”> 
<INPUT TYPE=”HIDDEN” NAME=”hpp_key” VALUE=”dpHsjh4GSr4g”> 
<INPUT TYPE=”HIDDEN” NAME=”charge_total” VALUE=”1.00”> 
Credit Card:<INPUT TYPE=”text” NAME=”cc_num” VALUE=”4242424242424242”><br> 
Exp Month:<INPUT TYPE=”text” NAME=”expMonth” VALUE=”04”><br> 
Exp Year:<INPUT TYPE=”text” NAME=”expYear” VALUE=”07”><br> 
<INPUT TYPE=”SUBMIT” NAME=”SUBMIT” VALUE=”Clickto process transaction”> 
</FORM>
```

Here's how you send a DirectPost purchase to the USA Gateway  (USD):

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="https://esplusqa.moneris.com/DPHPP/index.php" > 
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="dp_id" VALUE="DNVRTqa002"><br> 
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="dp_key" VALUE="dp4IJ78RD5BM"><br><br> 
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="amount" VALUE="1.00"><br><br> 
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="order_no" VALUE ="oid43333"> 
Card Number:<input type="text" name=cc_num value="4242424242424242"><br> 
Expiry Month:<input type="text" name=exp_month value="06"> 
Expiry Year:<input type="text" name=exp_year value="07"><br><br> 
<input type="hidden" name=crypt_type value="7"> 
<!--MORE OPTIONAL VARIABLES CAN BE DEFINED HERE --> 
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="SUBMIT" VALUE="Click to process transaction"> 
</FORM>
```

You can see from above that the fields are the same but their names are slightly different depending on which gateway your using.